# How to test aiohttp server?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, aiohttp

This is the code I've found in aiohttp docs:

```
async def test_hello(aiohttp_client):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', hello)
    client = await aiohttp_client(app)
```

This uses aiohttp_client pytest fixture. The problem is that it creates a new `web.Application()`, while my code already have a web.Application(). so Should I import it from the testing modules? Does it mean I need to expose it as a global variable (which I prefer not to)?

My `server.py` code looks like:

```
async def init():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes(.. )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(init())
loop.run_forever()
```

So my `app` is not a global variable here.

Second, does it possible, and is it correct, to actually run the server somehow before starting pytest? Because as I see these tests just interact with `web.Application()` itself, without listening to port and spawning a server process.

Comment: What level are you trying to test at? If you're testing your application, you could try interacting via the HTTP interface with a library like `requests`. Starting your server could be done in tests' setup or teardown stages.